# Python: cross correlation between two series

Tags: python, correlation

I am trying to find out a function that compute cross correlation (lead-lag correlation) between two series, and find out the lead-lag value that produces the maximum correlation but I can't find it on the web. Could someone show me a function and/or an example? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think do you need use is numpy's correlate function. here is the docs (with examples):
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

Edit:
Scipy also has a function:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html